# Appending String[][] object

Tags: java, android

How can i append this String[][] data element.

```
String[][] data = new String[][] {{},{},{"Link 1","Link 2"},{},{}};
```

Expected result:

```
data = new String[][] {{"value1,value2"},{},{"Link 1","Link 2"},{},{"value3,value4"}};
```

Comment: Where does "value1,value2" come from?

Comment: from server side json array

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do? Do you have Strings with the new values? Where do you know where they have to go?

Comment: so.. you want to append what to what?

Comment: say append String = "element1,element2,element3"; to third position in data

Comment: So why exactly is this not a Map<String, String> or a List<String[]> depending on what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed length so if you want to add elements to an empty array you have to create another with enough capacity.

```
String[][] data = new String[][] {{},{},{"Link 1","Link 2"},{},{}};

data[0] = new String[]{"value1,value2"};
data[4] = new String[]{"value3,value4"};
```

gives your expected value of

```
[["value1,value2"],[],["Link 1","Link 2"],[],["value3,value4"]]
```

Now if you want to append String `"element1,element2,element3"` to the 3rd position:

```
int oldLen = data[2].length;
String[] arr = new String[oldLen + 1];
System.arraycopy(data[2], 0, arr, 0, oldLen);
arr[oldLen] = "element1,element2,element3";
data[2] = arr;
```

and data should now be:

```
[["value1,value2"],[],["Link 1","Link 2","element1,element2,element3"],[],["value3,value4"]]
```

Comment: where are the braces ?

Comment: `newStr = newStr.replace("[", "{")` and `newStr = newStr.replace("]", "}")` to get braces.

Comment: @Dimitri What braces? I did the code by hand, but I believe it compiles. The 2nd line (after each example), is the array string representation.

Comment: should replace all "[" by "{" and "]" by "}"

Comment: No. {} can only be used to initialize an array. The correct way to print an array is with square brackets, like android.util.Arrays.arrayToString() (this method does not correctly handle multi-dimensional arrays)

Comment: Why not List<String[]>?